# sql transacional

Tags: php, transact-sql

[image: como aqui tengo un metodo que recibe el query o varios querys y estara ejecutandose el transational]

Como se debería utilizar los sql_transaccional eje:

```
public function consultar( $sql )
{
    try {
        $query = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute();
            $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $query;
    } catch (PDOException $pdo_e) {
        funciones::logs(1, 'DBConsulta', "Error en la consulta: (".$pdo_e->getMessage().") ".$sql );
        die("Error en la consulta: (".$pdo_e->getMessage().") ".$sql);
    }
}
```

o desde se iria a ejecutar el metodo o forma correcta de ejecutar las transaciones

```
function transaciones()
{
    try {
        $pdo->beginTransational();
        //aqui realizo el crud de sql
        $pdo->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $pdo->rollback();
    }
}
```

Comment: yo no veo nada malo en lo que haces.. que problemas tuviste?

Comment: no eso en mi codigo tengo una clase dond establescco la conexion y dentro de la misma ay un metodo que hace el crud mi pregunta es si dentro del mismo metodo puedo tener los sql-transation

Comment: Mostra lo que tenes y lo que estas tratando de hacer... si no, no queda claro que necesitas